# ASP.Net with xds file Web Application Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, dataset

The website works on my local box, but once I've deployed it I get an error with the mySQL adapter.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 .Net 4 and the most recent copies of mySQL and its .Net connector. The error I'm getting references the location that I deployed it from.

I constructed the website with a BLL and a DAL, the DAL contains a dataset xds and this seems to be the origin of the problem.

[This is the address](http://bodyguardhealthclub.com.au.173-248-177-8.cld1.temphostspace.com/index.aspx) that it's at currently, the index and membership pages work as the data is pulled from the BLL not from the DAL as the data is transformed first, and this lives in a try catch that catches the error. If you navigate to the supplements page you get the error because there is a `ObjectDataSource` connected directly to the dataset and there's no try catch there.

We have tried multiple methods for trying to fix the error and myself and a friend have searched for a resolution to the problem, but we can't find anything that works.

I am only new to this as is he, so I don't have any experience to draw on and would appreciate any help with this.

Here's the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

Added this:

```xml
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.3.7.0" newVersion="6.5.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

And changed the properties of my referenced `MySql.Data` library for `CopyLocal` to `True`.